# javascript events MOUSEOVER and CLICK during mobile simulator

Tags: javascript

I have a div with id "btn", and add two listeners to this div.

```
btn.addEventListener('click'){
    console.log('click')
}
```

and

```
btn.addEventListener('mouseover'){
    console.log('mouseover')
}
```

So when I turn on to chrome mobile simulator and I click on this div the result is 'click' AND 'mouseover'.

My question is how I can separate this two listeners. For example when I click on this button I want to fire just click event or just mouseover event, not both.

Thanks

Comment: There are two event listener available, onmousemove and onclick . Use which is needed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When you click both events occur. Like first mouse goes there so mouseover event occur and then click event occur on clicking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Why cant you try preventing event using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need both, just remove one of them. If you need to have them both, but only want one of them to fire when a mobile device is being used, see below.

---

Both are fired because both actions (click and mousover) are physically occurring. To my knowledge, there is no way to block one of them.

However, you could add a condition in one of them that prevents the program from going further if the user is using a mobile device, e.g.

```
btn.addEventListener('click'){
   if (!/Mobi|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        // This will only fire if the user is NOT using a mobile device
        console.log('click')
   }
}

btn.addEventListener('mouseover'){
    // This will fire every time
    console.log('mouseover')
}
```

There are different ways to test if a mobile device is being used, which you'd be better off asking about in a separate question should you need to, [but this should help you get started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @BigApp7e did it answer your question? If so, could you mark it as accepted. If not, I'm happy to answer any further questions.